# Storing AMRatingController stars

Tags: ios7, controller

[Update]
Using a different controller (mmStarRating) from here: https://www.iphonelife.com/blog/31369/unleash-your-inner-app-developer-adding-navigation. But im in the same boat. I got all the visual done and it looks good, but I cant figure out how to get what the user has inputted and save it into the attribute. After that I even have to fetch it out again and cant figure out how to convert it to the stars again. Please someone help, im touching the finish line for this app but cant cross it.

[Old Post]
Im trying to make a 5 star rating system using the controller AMRatingController. Im using xcode 5 and ios7. I got the stars and dots to display by importing the images and using this code:

```
    UIImage *dot, *star;
dot = [UIImage imageNamed:@"dot.png"];
star = [UIImage imageNamed:@"star.png"];
AMRatingControl *imagesRatingControl = [[AMRatingControl alloc] initWithLocation:CGPointMake(110, 250)
                                                                      emptyImage:dot
                                                                      solidImage:star
                                                                    andMaxRating:5];
[self.view addSubview:imagesRatingControl];
```

But now I want to store the rating the user put into an attribute in the appetizers entity. I dont find anywhere how to get this info from what I have so far. I have other attributes working like "name" and things but I get the info the user inputted from a text field then setvalue to the corresponding attributes. But in this case I dont see how to make it something I can store. Right now its just showing the dots and I can put stars. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Just add this code

```
 myRatingControl.editingChangedBlock = ^(NSUInteger rating)
{

 //do whatever you need to do with rating number. 

    NSLog(@"%d", rating);
    myValue = rating;

};
```

This block is called every time you press on the star.